Can I call a cashier in a store a “clerk”?
Can I call a cashier in a supermarket a “clerk”? Or does “clerk” refer to only a specific kind of employee? I’m wondering if “clerk” is a general term that can refer to all the normal employees in a store (excluding management, of course). I’m looking for such a general term. Can I use “worker”? Is it disrespectful if you call an employee in a store a “worker”? I’ve consulted the dictionaries. Thank you.

What parts didn't the dictionaries answer? See sense 3 in the first definition on https://www.thefreedictionary.com/clerk

@alphabet, "Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary" doesn't have that meaning. That's why I'm not sure.

Dictionaries are far more likely to omit senses of a word than to include incorrect ones, so surely its presence in the dictionary I cites is sufficient to establish its correctness.

@alphabet, my dictionaries don’t answer any of my questions. That’s why I made the post. Another example’s the word “worker”. The dictionaries don’t tell me if it’s disrespectful to call an employee an “worker”. I asked this because I probably heard somebody say it’s disrespectful. It’s a long time ago so I don’t remember clearly.

You can't in British English; here a clerk (pron. clark) is an office worker, someone whose job traditionally involved writing.

If dictionaries can’t answer your question, then it’s susceptible to being closed as calling for opinions. There are many words that are very widely used but are considered by this or that segment to be offensive.

@PaulTanenbaum, opinions are not necessarily wrong and can be supported by theories outside dictionaries. Questions that can be answered by a dictionary can be closed; questions that can’t be answered can also be closed; gee, what can I ask here?

As our Help Center explains, “Some subjective questions are allowed, but ‘subjective’ does not mean “anything goes’.” It then enumerates qualities that make subjective questions great fodder for ELU.

And please do note that I myself have provided an answer.

@PaulTanenbaum, thank you for replying. You were talking about answers first, which are outside my control, but as I said, opinions can be correct. Then you were talking about my questions. My questions are legitimate. I sincerely don’t know the answers. I don’t know if they have “objective” answers. How can I know that before I make the post? Not knowing that was the very reason I asked those questions. Every question has to be somewhat subjective. We’re not robots. You can’t erase subjectivity altogether. The text in the “Help Center” should really be rewritten.

Anyone is welcome to offer specific suggestions for ways to improve our Help Center—or indeed specific proposed modifications to our policies. Those are off topic right here on ELU and belong instead on our meta site. Of course, any such recommendations must achieve a consensus of the community in order to be accepted. And it’s possible that your concerns reflect an unfamiliarity with the reasoning behind the existing policies and documentation. I encourage you to investigate to familiarize yourself with ELU’s “culture.”

If you need 'a general term that can refer to all the normal employees in a store', isn't the most obvious solution to just use employees?

@PaulTanenbaum, 1. I didn’t want to talk about the “Help Center”, you brought up that unrelated topic. 2. I’m very familiar with the common mistakes around subjectivity and objectivity. Familiarity with a wrong "culture" can oftentimes hinder you from philosophizing it and discovering its mistakes.

@jsw29, thank you for replying. I realized that after posting the question. Haha. Let me give you an example. When I’m in a store, I want to say “Hi, x, can you help me”. If I use “employee” for x, does it sound weird? I don’t know what exact x does in the store, but I know he/she works there. That’s why I want to use a general term.

@Phoenix, oh, in that case, it is not clear why you would need x at all. Something like 'Good morning. I was wondering if you can help me?' will work just fine. And for cashiers in a supermarket, you usually don't need even that, as you are already standing face-to-face when interacting with them, and the scope of the interaction is very limited.

@jsw29, 1. I wanted to add x because that’s how I say it in my native language. People learning a second language translate literally from their native language. Old habits die hard, especially when you don’t know the idiomatic expressions. 2. What if the employee’s far away from me and I have to yell at him? I want him to know that I’m addressing him, not other customers around him. What word should I use to call him in a store when I don't know what exactly he does?

As to the first part of your question—about cashiers—Merriam-Webster gives as its definition 3c of clerk “one who works at a sales or service counter,” and it provides the usage example a grocery clerk. So yes, and this is very common in the U.S.
Whether anyone like a stocker (of merchandise onto the shelves) or a butcher might take offense at being included within the extension of clerk is pretty much an individual matter.

The OP asked whether worker can be disrespectful, not whether clerk can be.

The OP also asks whether a cashier can be called a clerk. The answer is Yes.
